# iOS Text editor with non-blinking caret

Tags: ios, text-editor

I would like to do some light text editing on my iPad. I would like to do it in an app that *has* a caret (the vertical line at the text insertion point), but in which the caret does not blink. I strongly dislike blinking in my user interface. Does anyone know of an app in which the caret does not blink, or in which the blink period can be changed in the settings?